# Using Twitter4j, how do I stream status updates authored or retweeted from one user?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm using Twitter4j's `TwitterStream` functionality to receive a stream of a heavily followed Twitter user's tweets, as follows:

```
...

private void initTwitterStream(AccessToken accessToken) {
    twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
    twitterStream.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    twitterStream.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
    twitterStream.addListener(createUserStreamListener());
    twitterStream.user("realDonaldTrump");
    logger.info("Listener initiated; listening for status updates.");
}

private UserStreamListener createUserStreamListener() {
    return new UserStreamAdapter() {

        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            log(status); // logs the tweet author and text
        }

    };
}

...
```

The problem I have is that I'm getting updates from anyone who has tagged this user in their tweet.  For example:

```
16:22:02.150 [Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]] INFO  c.d.i.twitter.TwitterListenerService - Received status update from [foo1234]: @realDonaldTrump never trust a man's perspective of technology after he uses "cyber" as a noun
```

How do I configure Twitter4j so that I only receive tweets authored by this user, and not tweets that mention him?

Comment: im not sure what the API supports but if you find that you can't filter specifically for this case, you would simply check any returned results for your own criteria and ignore all other tweets

Comment: Try getUser(). http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html#getUser--